# Condense Multiline File to CSV with vim

Tags: vim, csv, format

I've got a multiline file that I would like to turn into a csv with vim.

```
value1
value2
value3
```

I would like:

```
value1, value2, value3
```

I tried

```
:%s/%/, /g
```

But that doesn't put them on the same line

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried using new line as your replace character? `:s/\n/, /g`